# how to mock snmp4j framework

Tags: java, mocking, jmock, snmp4j

Can anyone provide me some idea on how to mock snmp4j framework?
There are many complex class hierarchy in it and I am not able decide which classes should i mock?

Is there any built-in class/agent to test snmp ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample scenario which is more specific so that it is easier to point out which class should be mocked?

Comment: Why do you want to mock it? I'd suggest not mocking it - instead wrap it in a class with an interface you specify and just assume that it the framework works as it should.

Comment: I'm currently in desperate need of mock `TableEvents`, for instance.